# Deleted custom Amazon Beanstalk AMI id

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami

I used custom AMI for my beanstalk environment. Then I deleted that and now can't access the environment. But the worst thing is that I cannot delete that env! How can I do that?

> ERROR: Configuration validation exception: Unable to look up root device name for image 'ami-00e96bXX'.

Answer (score 4):

We just had the same problem, to delete it, I used the AWS PowerShell tools.

```
Get-EBEnvironment | Where EnvironmentName -like "Your environment" |Select EnvironmentId

Stop-EBEnvironment -EnvironmentId xxxx
```

You can also use -EnvironmentName although when checking with WhatIf it was blank so I used the EnvironmentId.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the AWS CLI.

```
aws elasticbeanstalk terminate-environment --environment-name "Your environment Name"
```

No quotes